# How can i make AEM component 'un-cached' in the dispatcher

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I wish to make a specific AEM component un-cached in the dispatcher.
Can anyone let me know, how this can be implemented?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispatcher caches page level information as it has no knowledge about components and constructs of the pages.

What you are looking for is something called 'Service Side Include' or more aptly for AEM, '[Sling Dynamic Include](http://www.aemquickstart.in/2016/12/sling-dynamic-include.html)'. This is more to do with Apache server rather than dispatcher.

In a nutshell, you program your pages to have place holders for pulling in cached fragments. The page cache then becomes independent of of the component cache and performs more efficiently as a whole.

Read the article for more details.

Comment: This is the right answer. I just want to add that another possible way would be to use Javascript to add the information, that should not be cached, to the component.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I think that should be provided as a separate answer so that both topics can be covered independently...